# $c(-\frac{b}{a})y + dy = 0$ can be rewritten $(ad-bc)y=0$. How?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My textbook says that $c(-\frac{b}{a})y + dy = 0$ can be rewritten $(ad-bc)y=0$. How?

I would first do this:
$$ (\frac{-bc}{a})y + dy = 0 $$

then:
$$ (-bc)(\frac{1}{a})y + dy = 0 $$

then rearrange:
$$ dy - (bc)(\frac{1}{a})y = 0 $$

then factor:
$$ (d - bc\frac{1}{a})y = 0.$$

But if this is correct so far, then I don't understand how to get to what is in the textbook:
$$ (ad-bc)y=0. $$

Put another way, I think that the left hand side of my last equation and the textbook equation are not equal:

$$(d - bc\frac{1}{a})y \neq (ad-bc)y$$

easy to see if we plug in some example numbers (a=2, b,c,d=1, y≠0):

$$(1 - \frac{1}{2})y \neq (2-1)y$$

$$(\frac{1}{2})y \neq (1)y.$$

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Linear algebra is not relevant here

Comment: Well $dy$ seems to be the differential of $y$ because of the tags.

Comment: @knight i dont think so

Comment: @Shamim Okay :)

Comment: I really doubt your substitution in the last step is valid. I think this equation isn't valid for any $a,b,c,d$

Comment: @sai-kartik obviously, the polynomial has to be zero which doesnt occur in his substitution

Comment: @Shamim true that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could directly simplify the expression on the first line itself by multiplying $a$ throughout (of course assume that $a \neq 0$)
Like so:
$$c\left(-\frac ba\right)y+dy=0$$
Multiplying throughout with $a:$
$$c(-b)y+ady=0 $$
Rearranging:
$$ady-bcy=0$$
Factoring out $y:$
$$(ad-bc)y=0$$
There's your simplified expression!